"module java.base does not "opens java.nio.charset" to unnamed module" in new Spring resource
So, I am building out architecture for user functionality in a new app, written in Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.2.5. I'm consistently getting error logs containing the message above.
Here is the domain object I'm using, less getters and setters:
public class User extends RepresentationModel<User> {

    private final String email;
    private final String password;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    @JsonCreator
    public User(@JsonProperty("email") String email, @JsonProperty("password") String password, @JsonProperty("firstName") String firstName, @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

I'm using Mongo for my persistence layer, and using a bean to assemble a MongoTemplate from the required, overridden methods in the extended, abstract Mongo configuration interface:
@Configuration
public class MongoGeneral extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    @NonNull
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "flawless-beans";
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb+srv://" + username + ":" + password + "@cluster0.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0");
        System.out.println(username+", "+password);
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();
        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }

    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplate")
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(mongoClient(), getDatabaseName()));
    }

}

Just to do a conceptual task, I'm using the main class to do a pull for all the objects; I'll remove it when I'm ready to abstract things out:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoGeneral.class);
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = context.getBean("mongoTemplate", MongoTemplate.class);
        mongoTemplate.findAll(User.class);
        SpringApplication.run(FlawlessBeansJavaSpringApiApplication.class, args);
    }

Problem is, I keep getting these errors, and neither Google nor experimentation have helped:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.nio.charset.Charset(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio.charset" to unnamed module @55141def
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:391)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:367)

There are many more lines after that, but none under new headings; this seems to be an error with many causes, so research hasn't born fruit. However, these are the last three lines:
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getCollectionName(MongoTemplate.java:505)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findAll(MongoTemplate.java:1852)
    at com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.FlawlessBeansJavaSpringApiApplication.main(FlawlessBeansJavaSpringApiApplication.java:17)

This last log is the line executing mongoTemplate.findAll(User.class); I'm not surprisedby this, because the app starts fine when that line is commented out, and only breaks on re-addition.
I can start the app without console errors even when I purposely break the config password, so I expect connection errors, but this seems local (and these errors, if Google results are to be considered, occur in lots of places).

add --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED to your VM options

I bet you are not the first one having that problem (with similar packages) on this site - search should help find some

Using --add-opens will fix this error quickly. But it would probably be a good idea to figure out why this error is occurring to see if there's a "better" way to fix this. If you want help with that, I think we'll need a proper [mre]. That means don't omit imports or the enclosing class of a method. Include your build configuration (e.g., POM for Maven, build.gradle for Gradle, etc.) with all dependencies and their versions. Provide the full stack trace of the error. We should be able to copy-paste everything and run it as is.

Just checking, are you using the right dependency version of spring mongo? Could you by mistake bring an incompatible version of spring mongo maybe from a parent pom or so?
